# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined with d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I've been stuck on this problem for hours at this point and I can't figure out the problem.

I've been following http://bost.ocks.org/mike/map/ with my own data set.

The error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined - topojson.v0.min.js:1

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

path {
  fill: #ccc;
  stroke: #fff;
  stroke-width: .5px;
}

path:hover {
  fill: red;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<script src="../static/js/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="../static/js/topojson.v0.min.js"></script>
<script>


var width = 900,
    height = 900;

var path = d3.geo.path();

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);


d3.json("../static/json/newjerseymun.json", function(nj) {
  svg.append("path")
      .datum(topojson.object(nj, nj.objects.subunits))
      .attr("d", d3.geo.path().projection(d3.geo.mercator()));
});

</script>

</body>
```

Here is a sample of the beginning of my json file: http://pastebin.com/g0Lut36V

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem seems to be in the file `../static/json/newjerseymun.json`.

The segment of the `newjerseymin.json` you have posted does have the field `objects` which contains a JSON object but there does not seem to be a `subunits` field in that object, not at least in the segment you have posted. Hence, `ns.objects.subunits` would be `undefined` which causes the error.